# Can not connect to MySQL in a thread in python (fine on main thread)

Tags: python, mysql, multithreading, mysql-python

**Problem in short:** `MySQLdb.connect()` works on main thread, doesn't work in other threads.

I have a class called `Bot` with some methods.
something like this:

```
class Bot():
    def task1():
        read_from_db()
        # some other work
    def task2():
        read_from_db()
        # some other work
```

and i have a thread class which accepts a `Bot` object and a `task_name` and starts the task on the bot object.

```
class taskThread (threading.Thread):
def __init__(self, bot, task):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.bot = bot
    self.task = task
def run(self):
    print "Starting " + self.task + " for " + self.bot.username

    if self.task == "task1":
        self.bot.task1()

    elif self.task == "task2":
        self.bot.task2()
    print "Exiting " + self.task + " for " + self.bot.username
```

I tried every thing in `read_from_db()` but it does not work in a thread.
it works fine if i call `bot.task1()` in main thread but if i create a myThread object and tell it to run task1 it stops exactly on `MySQLdb.connect()` line with no error. it just stops.

```
def read_from_db():
        db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",
                        user="root",
                        passwd="",
                        db="db_name",
                        unix_socket="/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock") 
    db.set_character_set('utf8')
```

I have searched a lot but i couldn't find anything.

**edit:** weirdly when the code is stopped right before creating a connection to db, if i press ctrl+c in terminal (where i ran the code) the code resumes and works just as expected.
do anyone know such a behavior ?

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with your `def run(self):`. You're referencing a `task` variable that isn't defined. You mean `self.task`:

```
# Consider renaming: it's more standard to have `TaskThread`
class taskThread (threading.Thread):
    # Init is fine
    def run(self):
        print "Starting " + self.task + " for " + self.bot.username

        # It used to be just 'task'. Make it self.task
        if self.task == "task1":
            self.bot.task1()

        elif self.task == "task2":
            self.bot.task2()
        print "Exiting " + self.task + " for " + self.bot.username
```

You also might want to consider:

```
    def run(self):
        print "Starting " + self.task + " for " + self.bot.username

        action = getattr(self.bot, self.task)
        action()
        print "Exiting " + self.task + " for " + self.bot.username
```

Comment: thanks but the first one was a typo, it is not like that in the actual code. but your second point was a good suggestion thank you,